# using set state in a data table source in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I want to use `setState()` inside a `DataTableSource` class to when a button is pressed. so how can i accomplish that?

```
class MyTable extends DataTableSource {
  MyTable({required this.datasList, required this.context});
  final List<User> datasList;
  BuildContext context;
  final UserController userController = Get.put(UserController());

  Widget Button(String title, Color color, String id) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        deleteUser(id);
        
      },
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: color,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    );
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(index: index, cells: [
      DataCell(Text(datasList[index].id.toString())),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
        child: Text(
          datasList[index].name.toString(),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      )),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].username.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].email.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].roles![0].name.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(Row(
        children: [
          Button("Edit", Colors.lightBlue, datasList[index].id.toString()),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Button("Delete", Colors.red, datasList[index].id.toString()),
        ],
      )),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => datasList.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

it is passed as below in my `stateful` class

```
DataTableSource dataSource(List<User> userList) =>
      MyTable(datasList: userList, context: context);
```

any solution?

the `main` page

```
StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
                        stream: fetchUsersFromModel().asStream(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return PaginatedDataTable(
                                sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                                sortAscending: isAscending,
                                columns: [
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Id"), onSort: onSort),
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Name"),
                                      onSort: onSort),
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Username"),
                                      onSort: onSort),
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Email"),
                                      onSort: onSort),
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Roles"),
                                      onSort: onSort),
                                  DataColumn(
                                      label: const Text("Actions"),
                                      onSort: onSort),
                                ],
                                header: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Manage Users",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                    ),
                                    MaterialButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (context) => SizedBox(
                                                  height: height * 0.9,
                                                  child: BottomSheetWidget(),
                                                ),
                                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                    topLeft:
                                                        Radius.circular(15),
                                                    topRight:
                                                        Radius.circular(15))));
                                      },
                                      color:
                                          const Color.fromRGBO(30, 119, 66, 1),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Add User",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: width * 0.03),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                source:
                                    dataSource(snapshot.data! as List<User>));
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                          }
                          return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        })
```

deleteUser call

```
Future deleteUser(var id) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}user/$id");
  final response = await http.delete(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
  }).then((value) => {
        //usersToJson(usersFromJson(value.body)),
        Get.snackbar("Deleted $id", "${value.body}",
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
            colorText: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      });}
```

Comment: you use Getx, so... why you don't control this state with getx and add a Obx in you code?

Comment: @SergioClemente i wanted to handle it with setState. i actually wrap my button with `StatefulBuilder()` but it didn't work

Comment: using Getx with obx you can do this in easy way.

Comment: @SergioClemente how can i controll that button press?

Comment: when deleteuser what action you want to do?

Comment: @SergioClemente in my `UserController` i did as follows `void deleteUser(var id) {
    deleteUser(id);
  }` but it still didn't work

Comment: @SergioClemente i called `final UserController userController = Get.put(UserController());` in `DataTableSource` directly and used it `userController.deleteUser(id);`

Comment: I will create an example for u, but i don't see in you code what state you can update when call deleteuser. And what this state do.

Comment: @SergioClemente I'm using `StreamBuilder` and when user deletes or creates i want to update ui. i used in d/t button which was in `stateful` widget and when deleted it updated ui. b/c i used `setState`.

Comment: @SergioClemente so I would like to do the same ui update when clicking from `DataTableSource`.

Comment: @SergioClemente added the streambuilder above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Getx. So, use Getx to controll this state...

in you UserController :

```
final _deleteUserPress = false.obs;
  get deleteUserPress => _deleteUserPress.value;
  set deleteUserPress(value) => _deleteUserPress.value = value;


setdeleteUserPress(bool value){
  deleteUserPress = value;
  update();
}
```

when deleteuser call :

```
onPressed: () {
  deleteUser(id);
  userController.setdeleteUserPress(true);
},
```

in yout Screen :

```
Obx(() => 
    userController.deleteUserPress
     ? // do someting
     : // do else
);
```

### And if needed you set userController.deleteUserPress to false again

Edit ..

Or put the setDeleteUserPress In your deleteUser :

```
Future deleteUser(var id) async {
  final UserController userController = Get.put(UserController());

  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}user/$id");
  final response = await http.delete(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
  });

  userController.setdeleteUserPress(true);

  Get.snackbar("Deleted $id", "${response.body}",
     duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
        colorText: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white),
  });}
```

Comment: i actually wraped with `Obx` but after reload it didn't affect the data. the row still exists. only when hot reloded it gets deleted.

Comment: Perhaps you need to controll the deleteuser function. but this code will work if the data is affected or not. In this example the var deleteUserPress is call after deleteUser is call. But, if you want, you can put a await in deleteuser function or call deleteUserPress inside deleteuser function.

Comment: i did await. first i set the press to true then await deleteUser and turn back the press to false.

Comment: i aded the streambuilder above

Comment: put your deleteuser code,please

Comment: check it out now

Comment: we made it bro.